# Can we retain static ip from ec2 to lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I have an IP address in EC2, Can we retain static IP **from EC2 to lightsail ?**

Comment: I think you'd better open a support ticket. Those AWS folks may be able do this manually for you.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Did you create an Elastic IP address (which is static), or is it an automatically-assigned public IP address? In general, you should use DNS Names that map to IP addresses, which allows an IP address to change without impacting a system. Why do you need to keep this particular IP address?